# Resource Constrained Scheduling Project Using Pyschedule

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, or-tools, mixed-integer-programming, cp-sat

#### Introduction:

I am working on a Resource Constraint Project Scheduling Problem (RCPS) and I was looking for some guidance. This is an optimization problem at its root.

Currently, I am using a library called Pyschedule where I can define an objective, and then add various constraints such as capacity constraints, precedence constraints, etc.

#### My project overview is this: Given a set of jobs that require either a certain amount of CPU/GPU compute, allocate the resource plan (the limited CPU/GPU compute that we have available) to a set of jobs in order to optimize the maximum amount of jobs completed with a specific time frame.

#### Here are the constraints for the project:

- Jobs must have staggering start times of 15 minutes (The second job that is scheduled has to start at least 15 minutes after the first job, and so on and so forth).
- There is limited CPU/GPU compute (Limited Resources)
- Only 5 jobs can be scheduled in parallel
- There is a limited horizon (All jobs must be completed within a maximum period, for ex: 12 hrs)
- Different jobs have different priorities
- The amount of resources available changes per hour (Resource Plan)

#### The Main Problem I'm Facing:

Currently, in the pyschedule library you have to define a length (service time) for a task, so essentially a task/job will require a certain amount of CPU/GPU compute to be completed.
But the issue is, is that the jobs that I am working with have varying service times depending on the resources given to it.
For example: A job that requires 10 CPUs and 5 GPUs can finish in one hour, but if you give it 20CPUs and 10GPUs it can finish in 30 minutes. So the length(service time) varies on the amount of resources you give it.

How should I best go about tackling this issue and is there a better library in python than "pyschedule" to solve this problem?

#### Example Code in Pyschedule:

S = Scenario('Schedule Optimization',horizon=720) #720 represents 12 hours in minutes

CPU, GPU = S.Resource('CPU'), S.Resource('GPU')

job1 = S.Task('Job1', length = 20) #

#### So in this example this would represent that job1 needs 10 CPU and 5 GPU to be completed in 20 minutes

#### Conclusion:

Any help is appreciated, I have been stuck on this issue for some time now and I want to know if there is another direction I should head in or if there is a better approach that I am not aware of,

Thank you for taking the time to read my question!

Answer (score 0):

We have very good results with the current code using OR-Tools CP-SAT and this example: [rcpsp_sat](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/main/examples/python/rcpsp_sat.py)

But beware, this is not a package library, solver. This is a example that builds a model to solve problems from the RCPSP academic benchmarks.

You will need to understand the current code to adapt it to your specific case.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I’ll be looking into restructuring the code to fit my specific case

Comment: When defining a task we have to define a start and end variable that requires a certain amount of resources to complete the task. However, what if the end time variable has a relationship with the number of resources given to it. For example, if task 1 has 20 resources it will complete in 1 hour, but if it has 10 resources it will complete in 2 hours. The objective is to find optimal start times of a set of tasks/jobs given limited compute. But the tasks don't have an explicit service time. It fully depends on the resources allocated to it. Is it feasible to do this in OR-Tools?

Comment: This is the recipe part of the problem.